# WordPress - Multiple Author Newsletter

Tags: wordpress, newsletter, multisite, author

I've been looking for quite some time to find a Newsletter plugin for multi-author for a WordPress site.

Currently using a Multisite with MailPoet. This way, each author is assigned to a site and can build his newsletter without having access to other authors lists, posts and subscribers.

I'm currently looking to remove the multisite feature as it's causing more problem than it solves.

However, I'm still stuck and I can't find a decent plugin that will allow the author to build a custom newsletter from the WordPress backend - without having access to all other authors subscribers, posts and so on.

Mailpoet does everything I need, but it doesn't allow to associate lists and newsletter per author.

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Well, I really have no idea how you might isolate each author all sharing one WordPress site... It's reasonably simple to show an author only their own posts, but assigning specific users to only one author would be a bigger beast to tackle. If multisite is working for you but you don't like the nuances of it (Totally understand by the way, multisite can be a pain to administer), I might suggest installing many instances of wordpress, one for each author, and using something self-hosted like infinitewp to manage it. It'll be a bigger deal to set up initially, but it might work a lot smoother for you.

Comment: I finally used some custom code to modify the MailPoet plugin. I associated lists and newsletters by author_id. Changed the query to output only the ones that match with the current user. Only thing now is that you can add a post in your newsletter that was created by another author, not a big deal. Thanks for taking the time to respond.